# Changing link colors through theme switcher

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, themes

Link colors aren't changing with my simple theme switcher from tutorial. I wasn't able to find an answer online to the issue.

My code is below. I have tried changing the link colors and variables to make sure it wasn't a syntax issue. Likely the javascript either needs to be expanded or I'm missing something else.

HTML

```
    <div class="toggle">
        <button class="theme-btn ground" onclick="setTheme('ground')" title="ground scheme">ground</button>
        <button class="theme-btn ocean" onclick="setTheme('ocean')" title="ocean scheme">ocean</button>
    </div>
```

CSS snippet

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: var(--link-color);
    text-decoration: none;
}

:root,
    :root.ground {
        --bg-color: #fefae0;
        --text-color: #ffffff;
        --bg-card-color: #283618;
        --bg-collapse-color: #283618;
        --bg-collapse-color-hover: #606c38;
        --link-color: #bc6c25;
        --link-color-hover: #dda15e;
    }

    :root.ocean {
        --bg-color: #023047;
        --text-color: #000000;
        --bg-card-color: #219ebc;
        --bg-collapse-color: #219ebc;
        --bg-collapse-color-hover: #8ecae6;
        --link-color: #fb8500;
        --link-color-hover: #ffb703;
    }
```

Javascript

```
const setTheme = theme => document.documentElement.className = theme;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html there is (at least in this one that you shared here) no links attributes but buttons, that's reason One why is not going to change.

Now in your css snippet, I would suggest to have just root and not "root, root.ground", and also not sure which tutorial you watched, but that "root.ground" or  "root.ocean" is even correct, I will give you a functional example. But back to the point, root should be your default theme, so no need to stablish it twice. Now for your second theme, I would do it with [data-theme="ocean"], so full css code below:

```
  :root {
  --bg-color: #fefae0;
  --text-color: #ffffff;
  --bg-card-color: #283618;
  --bg-collapse-color: #283618;
  --bg-collapse-color-hover: #606c38;
  --link-color: #bc6c25;
  --link-color-hover: #dda15e;
}


[data-theme="ocean"] {
  --bg-color: #023047;
  --text-color: #000000;
  --bg-card-color: #219ebc;
  --bg-collapse-color: #219ebc;
  --bg-collapse-color-hover: #8ecae6;
  --link-color: #0082fb;
  --link-color-hover: #ffb703;
}

// I removed the "a" attributes and use button instead, because that's what you have  in your html

button {
  display: inline-block;
  color: var(--link-color);
  text-decoration: none;
}


body {
  background-color: var(--bg-color); // I added this extra so just to see the body to change
}
`
```

And I made a full functional sandbox with your example, [so you can see it working in this link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/wizardly-allen-vgzghk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Appreciate the help! I ended up keeping the old javascript since it allows for multiple themes but in between testing your solutions here and messing around with the code I modified I was able to get link colors to change. I'm not 100% sure what allowed this to work but as long as its operational that's all that matters.

Comment: well in theory, the old script works, just thought normally there are always only 2 themes on a website, at least of course is a huge system. To change the links , you just need it to add back the link class, in your html and of course declare an <a href=""> ...</a> in your html, but oh well I hope it helped somehow

Comment: It's ok originally the tutorial I used only had two themes. I reworked it for my own purposes but for some reason links weren't honoring the changes. Apparently it just needed me to mess with it some more. <a href=""> links also now honor the code as well. You definitely helped thanks for your input.